# Как в Qt designer сделать, чтобы слой начал прилипать к краям формы?

Tags: виджет, c++, qt, form

... например, Vertical Layout прилип к краям формы и растягивался вместе с ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто:

1. Бросаешь Vertical Layout;
2. Жмешь правой кнопкой на форму;
3. Layout->Layout in a Grid (ну или сразу Ctrl-G);

Comment: спасибо помогло